# Access site in vmware from host MAC machine browser issue

Tags: iis, iis-7, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, dotnetnuke

I have windows 7 installed in my MAC VmWare.
In windows I have dotNetNuke instalation hosted on iis.
I try to access this iis from MAC browser by typing ip address of my virtual machine:

```
192.168.x.y
```

This shows me IIS welcome message.
But when I try to access dotnetnuke...

```
192.168.x.y/dotnetnuke
```

I receive `404` error.
I can't find way to access this site from host machine :(
Firewall is turned off in windows.
VmWare is set to briged mode.

Comment: As you can access the IIS welcome page? The routing to your VM seems to work. Have you checked IIS manager to see of there is a virtual directory called dotnetnuke? Have you enabled asp.net in IIS features?

Comment: Yes I have dotetnuke in IIS it's under 'DefaultWebSite' I can access it in windows (I use it all the time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it. I have changed alias for portal in 192.xxx.yy.ss/myPortal and it worked.

Comment: SO short and incomplete answer!